# checkbox list example in mvc3 Razor,

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am converting my application in razor template,i used the `Html.CheckBoxlist` in one of my views.
Please suggest me how can I achieve this in razor

Here is my code:

```
@Html.CheckBoxlist("abc", Model.CheckBoxListItems)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) is simply a view engine it has nothing to do with the methods you call.
If you have such an html helper method, it should work with `@Html.CheckBoxlist(parameters)`